# How much clearance is required in front of a toilet in a NJ private home?

Tags: plumbing, code-compliance

As shown, 15 inches from front of toilet to side of vanity.   Will that fail inspection in NJ USA?

Note, the side to side width of the toilet space is 30 inches, I believe that is sufficient.

[image]

Comment: Public? Private? APA?

Comment: House.  Added to question, tx.  What's APA?  ADA?

Comment: Yes, ADA... got the typing wrong.

Comment: Perhaps a corner toilet would be suitable here.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica perhaps. If it was 1975 and I lived in the Poconos.  :-O

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code says 21” is required in front of toilet. Also, 15” is required from center of toilet to side wall or adjacent vanity. (See R307)

The ceiling height shall be 7’ high minimum. However, a toilet room can have a sloped ceiling as long as there is a 21” x 24” space in front of the toilet with a minimum ceiling height of 6’-4” high. (See R305)

Comment: So, "No." :(.    15" from center to side means a 30 inch opening is adequate, right?  (Seems obvious, but code compliance never seems to be that way.)

Comment: No, 30” opening is not the same as 15” from middle of toilet to side wall. If the toilet is installed a few inches off the center line it could be difficult for a large person to sit on the toilet.